# Can a Global Method Constructor for global form to be on a dynamic class using C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
public class Classname
{       
    private static nameOFform Somevariable;
    public static nameOFform GlobalForm 
    {
        get 
        {
            if (Somevariable == null || Somevariable.IsDisposed) 
            {
                Somevariable = new nameOFform();
            }
            return Somevariable;
        }
        set 
        {
            value = Somevariable;
        }
    }
}
```

Is it doable to put this method in a class and just call it in an instance function let's say => classname.makemyformglobal(formname); Which will be used each time a form is created to make it globalalize. is this possible? if it is then how can I make one method that is dynamic base on a form name created.

Comment: It is possible. Are you facing any problem?

Comment: What's a *Global Method Constructor*? What's a *dynamic class*?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question, you're looking into something which is usually implemented in c# with Generics.

```
public static class GlobalFormAccessor
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, object> _cache = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    public static TForm GetForm<TForm>()
        where TForm : class, new()
    {
        if (_cache.ContainsKey(typeof(TForm)))
        {
            _cache[typeof(TForm)] = new TForm();
        }
        return (TForm)_cache[typeof(TForm)];
    }

    public static void SetForm<TForm>(TForm form)
    {
        _cache[typeof (TForm)] = form;
    }
}
```

You could then call this method like:

`GlobalFormAccessor.GetForm<nameOFform>();`

where `nameOFform` is the type of your Form class.